# How can I store and retrieve data for fixed layouts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, data-structures

My question today is about a suitable way to store data when I want to create a fixed design. So imagine I have a given layout in a TikZ drawing, where I want to have dynamic text. However the user shall not be confronted with the TikZ code, he shall only define the content and I am filling it into TikZ nodes. So here is my example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(center)[fill=cyan,circle,minimum size=3cm] at (135:10cm) {Topic};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,7}
    {
        \node(bubble)[fill=green,text width=2cm,circle,align=center] at (\i*20:\i*3cm) {\textbf{Heading \i}\\Content};
        \draw (center) -- (bubble);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So my nodes are set, but what is a suitable way of providing data beforehand? Of course I could just define a macro for each node, as in:

```
\newcommand{\headingone}{Heading 1}
\newcommand{\contentone}{Content 1}
```

And then use these macros to read the data. But isn't there a simpler way which is more data driven. As the diagram should not dynamically grow, I don't want to create an environment with e.g. items, even though this looks like a possible approach to me. But isn't there a smarter way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe create two `clist`s and push the data in there, then retrieve it inside the `\foreach` loop? Something like this?

Comment: If you are trying to create a truly interactive document, you might use textfields from eforms.

Comment: @JohnKormylo if you mean https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/eformman.pdf then this is for interactive PDFs, but this is not, what I am looking for or I misunderstand your comment.

Answer (score 7):

I don't exactly know what you are after, but you could create two `clist`s and store the data there. In your `tikzpicture`, you can then retrieve the data inside the `\foreach` loop.

The exact implementation depends on the kind of data that you want to store, but for simple strings it could work like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_mypic_headers_clist 
\clist_new:N \l_mypic_contents_clist 

\NewDocumentCommand { \getHeadersAtIndex } { m } {
    \clist_item:Nn \l_mypic_headers_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \getContentsAtIndex } { m } {
    \clist_item:Nn \l_mypic_contents_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \getMaxIndex } { } {
    \clist_count:N \l_mypic_headers_clist
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \addToLists } { m m } { 
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_mypic_headers_clist { { #1 } }
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_mypic_contents_clist { { #2 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addToLists{Header 1}{Contents 1}
\addToLists{Header 2}{Contents 2}
\addToLists{Header 3}{Contents 3}
\addToLists{Header 4}{Contents 4}
\addToLists{Header 5}{Contents 5}
\addToLists{Header 6}{Contents 6}
\addToLists{Header 7}{Contents 7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(center)[fill=cyan,circle,minimum size=3cm] at (135:10cm) {Topic};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\getMaxIndex} {
        \node(bubble)[fill=green,text width=2cm,circle,align=center] at (\i*20:\i*3cm) 
        {\textbf{\getHeadersAtIndex{\i}} \\ \getContentsAtIndex{\i}};
        \draw (center) -- (bubble);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you need a more robust set-up, you can use squences instead of comma-lists for storing. Just replace every `clist` by `seq` in the code above.

---

**Edit**

You can add the following function inside the `ExplSyntax` block:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \addMultipleToLists } { m } { 
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_mypic_headers_clist { 
            \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 1 }
        }
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_mypic_contents_clist { 
            \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 2 }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use a maybe more convenient way to input the data (note that in this case you need to wrap text in additional braces if it contains a comma, and you cannot simply switch to sequences here obviously, since you feed the macro a comma-list in the first place):

```
\addMultipleToLists{{Header 1,Contents 1},
                    {Header 2,Contents 2},
                    {Header 3,Contents 3},
                    {Header 4,Contents 4},
                    {Header 5,Contents 5},
                    {Header 6,Contents 6},
                    {Header 7,Contents 7}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jasper, this looks close to what I was looking for, need to check if it works in my specific setup before accepting the answer however. One thing that I would like to ask, ist it possible to adjust `\addToLists{Header 1}{Contents 1}` so it accepts a format like `\addToLists{{Header 1,Contents 1},{{Header 2,Contents 2},{{Header 3,Contents 3}}}` or maybe simpler, but harder to grasp `\addToLists{Header 1,Contents 1,Header 2,Contents 2}`?

Comment: @TobiBS Sure, see my edit.

Comment: The names of the variables should have a prefix. I'd not use `\clist_push:Nn`, but `\clist_put_right:Nn`. The former is for using a `clist` as a stack, but it's not how you're employing them.

Comment: Yes, I had `\clist_put_right:Nn` originally, but wasn't sure what is better. Thanks for pointing to the prefix rule. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This PGFkeys supported solution supports both lists in the form of

```
{{Header 1, Content 1}, {Header 2, Content 2}, {…}, …}
```

as well as

```
{Header 1, Content 1, Header 2, Content 2, …
```

The latter is the default `list use = all comma`, the former can be used with `list use = tuples`.

For placing the green nodes, I'm using the [`chains`](https://tikz.dev/library-chains#pgf./tikz/on:chain) library's

```
on chain = <chain name> placed {at = (<calculation>)}
```

where `(<calculation>)` simply is

```
(\tikzchaincount*20: \tikzchaincount*3cm)
```

i.e. the same as yours but `\i` replaced by `\tikzchaincount`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  /utils/if not empty/.code 2 args={%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
                             \else\expandafter\pgfutil@firstofone\fi
                             {\pgfkeysalso{#2}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  % defaults
  topic style/.style={shape=circle, minimum size=3cm, fill=cyan},
  list style/.style={fill=green, text width=2cm, circle, align=center},
  topic/.initial=Topic,
  list/.initial={Header 1, Contents 1,
                 Header 2, Contents 2,
                 Header 3, Contents 3,
                 Header 4, Contents 4,
                 Header 5, Contents 5,
                 Header 6, Contents 6},
  % mantaining the lists/settings
  reset list/.style={list=},
  add to list/.style={list/.append={,#1}},
  list use/.is choice,
  list use/all comma/.style={use list/.style={% H1, C1, H2, C2, …
    list parser/.expand twice/.expand once={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/list},}}},
  list use/tuples/.style={use list/.style={% {H1, C1}, {H2, C2}, …
    placer/.list/.expand twice/.expand once=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/list}}},
  list use=all comma,% default: all comma
  % actual placing
  list parser/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{                   % parsing H1, C1, H2, C2, …
    placer={{#1},{#2}},
    /utils/if not empty={#3}{list parser={#3}}},
  tuples parser/.style args={#1,#2}{placer={{#1},{#2}}},% parsing {H1, C1}, {H2, C2}, …
  placer/.code args={#1,#2}{%
    \node [list style, on chain] {\textbf{#1}\\#2} edge (center);}}

\newcommand*\myTikz[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1,
   start chain=headers placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*20:\tikzchaincount*3cm)}]
   \node (center) [topic style] at (135:10cm) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/topic}};
   \tikzset{use list}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\myTikz
\myTikz[add to list={Header X, Content X, Header Y, Content Y}]
\myTikz[topic=\TeX, list={TikZ, extends PGF, \LaTeX, extends \TeX}]

\tikzset{
  list use=tuples,
  list={{Header 1, Contents 1},
        {Header 2, Contents 2},
        {Header 3, Contents 3},
        {Header 4, Contents 4},
        {Header 5, Contents 5},
        {Header 6, Contents 6}}}
\myTikz
\myTikz[add to list={{Header X, Content X}, {Header Y, Content Y}}]
\myTikz[topic=\TeX, list={{TikZ, extends PGF}, {\LaTeX, extends \TeX}}]
\end{document}
```